# How do I append each parent in JS without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, alt

I'd like to elegantly annotate an image with the contents of that image's alt tag and I do not want to use jQuery or anything else superfluous.

How do I append each parent in Javascript?

Here's what I have so far (which only works with jQuery):

```
// after jQuery
$('img', 'figure').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().append('<figcaption class="image-text">' + this.alt + '</figcaption>'); 
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lqxb4cp/

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You've only shared jQuery...

Comment: You might find this useful:  http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can transform with something like this:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("img");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var figCaption = '<figcaption>' + elements[i].getAttribute("alt") + '</figcaption>';
    elements[i].parentNode.innerHTML += (figCaption);
}
```

See it working : https://jsfiddle.net/y1rjL0qm/3/

Comment: `class="image-text"` isn't the `alt` text. That's what I'm stuck with.

Comment: `class` attribute is not `alt` attribute. What do you mean?

Comment: I convert your code in pure javascript non-jquery dependant code. That's what you ask.

Comment: Marcos, I'm not sure how to get it working. I've got a fiddle, what am I missing? https://jsfiddle.net/y1rjL0qm/1/

Comment: Your principal problem was select `<figure>` tag that's not the image and it throws undefined.

Answer (score 0):

## I Think this helps you in your work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var path = $(this).parent() ;
var image = '<figcaption class="image-text">' + this.alt + '</figcaption>';
$('img', 'figure').each(function() {
  path.appendChild(image); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried this and something similar, above... and it's not working properly. What am I missing? https://jsfiddle.net/y1rjL0qm/1/